# Uploading App bundle to Google Play Console gives, Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading error

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, google-play-console

When I added my app bundle into Google Play Console, it gives me following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIyS6.png)

Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading. The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers: com.veepmeep.app.androidx-startup, com.veepmeep.app.flutter.image_provider, com.veepmeep.app.flutter.share_provider.

**This is my AndroidManifest.xml -**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.veepmeep.app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:label="veep meep"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
        
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.veepmeep.app"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
                tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>


       <activity
           android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**This is my Pubspec.yaml file -**

```
name: veep_meep
description: Veep Meep flutter application
version: 0.1.0+46

environment:
    sdk: ">=2.17.3 <3.0.0"

dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
    flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
    change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
    http_mock_adapter: ^0.3.3
    flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0

dependency_overrides:
    flutter_pdfview: 1.2.9

flutter_icons:
    android: "launcher_icon"
        ios: true
    image_path: "images/png/app_icon.png"
    min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21

flutter:
    uses-material-design: true
    assets:
        - animations/
        - images/svg/
        - images/png/
        - fonts/
        - assets/sounds/chat_notifications.mp3
        - assets/sounds/voice_message.wav

    fonts:
        - family: SF-Pro
            fonts:
            - asset: fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Bold.otf
                weight: 700
            - asset: fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Semibold.otf
                weight: 600
            - asset: fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Medium.otf
                weight: 500
            - asset: fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Regular.otf
                weight: 400

dependencies:
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
    dio: ^4.0.6
    connectivity_plus: ^2.3.9
    permission_handler: ^10.1.0
    get_it: ^7.2.0
    shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
    equatable: ^2.0.5
    dartz: ^0.10.1
    flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1
    flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
    transparent_image: ^2.0.0
    lottie: ^1.4.3
    currency_text_input_formatter: ^2.1.7
    smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
    device_info_plus: ^8.1.0
    page_transition: ^2.0.9
    pinput: ^2.2.16
    flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
    flutter_switch: ^0.3.2
    swipe_cards: ^1.0.0
    material_segmented_control: ^4.0.0
    device_preview: ^1.1.0
    universal_platform: ^1.0.0+1
    grouped_list: ^5.1.2
    intl: ^0.18.0
    syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^20.4.43
    image_cropper: ^3.0.1
    path: ^1.8.0
    reorderable_grid_view: ^2.2.5
    proste_bezier_curve: ^2.0.2
    country_state_city_picker: ^1.2.8
    flutter_screenutil: ^5.6.1
    file_picker: ^5.2.5
    flutter_cached_pdfview: ^0.4.1
    flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
    share_plus: ^7.0.0
    camera: ^0.10.5+2
    icons_plus: ^3.0.0
    gallery_media_picker: ^0.1.0
    photo_view: ^0.14.0
    image_picker: ^0.8.9
    video_player: ^2.6.1
    record: ^4.4.4
    stop_watch_timer: ^2.0.0
    flutter_local_notifications: ^14.1.1
    timeago: ^3.4.0
    empty_widget: ^0.0.5
    fancy_shimmer_image: ^2.0.3
    heroicons_flutter: ^0.2.3
    appinio_video_player: ^1.2.1
    shimmer: ^3.0.0
    animated_icon: ^0.0.4
    emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.6.1
    loading_animation_widget: ^1.2.0+4
    action_slider: ^0.6.1
    animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
    latlong2: 
    flutter_map: 
    voice_message_package: 
        path: modified-libs/voice_message_player
    giphy_picker:
        path: modified-libs/giphy_picker
    open_street_map_search_and_pick: ^0.1.0
    geolocator: ^10.1.0
    flutter_card_swiper: ^6.0.0
```

I tried to add this app for internal testing in Google Play Console. I was hope this will upload in to it without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing name of your package, when I was releasing my app i got something similar my package was named myapp.com but apparently the same name was used by someone else too

Comment: but my name is unique and it has never been used in any other app